# route parameter contain slashes and dot does not recognized in new server

Tags: php, laravel

I used [thephpleague/glide](https://github.com/thephpleague/glide) package in my laravel application to resize images.

I wrote a route like below to get `width` , `height` and `path` of an image on the server and then using that package modify that image and return it.

```
Route::get('/showImage/{w}/{h}/{src}', [
        'as'   => 'showImage',
        'uses' => function (League\Glide\Server $server, $w, $h, $src) {
            $server->outputImage($src, ['w' => $w, 'h' => $h, 'fit' => 'crop']);
        }
    ])->where('src', '.+');
```

Suppose I requested `http://www.example.com/showImage/300/168/galleries/mypic.jpg` url. but while `galleries/mypic.jpg` is right and exists on the server , I got a **404 not found** error.

I have used exactly this route in other projects but on a new host I have encountered this problem.

I think that problem is on `src` parameter that can contain `/` and `.` signs. Because when I use a string without any `/` and `.` , that works and can access to `src` parameter.

Answer (score 1):

Escape the slash with `(.*)`:

```
Route::get('/showImage/{w}/{h}/{src}', [
            'as'   => 'showImage',
            'uses' => function (League\Glide\Server $server, $w, $h, $src) {
                $server->outputImage($src, ['w' => $w, 'h' => $h, 'fit' => 'crop']);
            }
        ])->where('src', '(.*)');
```

And run `composer dump-autoload` afterwards.
If you don't have access to ssh then add this route:

```
Route::get('/updateapp', function()
{
    system('composer dump-autoload');
    echo 'dump-autoload complete';
});
```

If this command didn't work run `composer dump-autoload` locally then upload the files with ftp

Comment: not worked, of course I do not run `composer dump-autoload` because I have not SSH access to run `composer` commands.

Comment: Now, `system() has been disabled for security reasons` error.

Comment: then try the last solution locally

Comment: just upload all files except for `vendor`

Comment: I tried your approach locally and then upload entire project to server. but same error is occurred.

Comment: i think it's something with the cache not the route

Comment: do `composer dump-autoload` and `php artisan route:clear` locally, then upload again